# Tensorflow slim import error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow version 0.11 in my ubuntu 14.04 with python 2.7. I am trying to import contrib.slim package. I am getting "AttributeError: module object no attribute 'cpu_count'"

I have added the full errorstack below:

```
>>> import tensorflow.contrib.slim
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-     packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
from tensorflow.contrib import factorization
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/factorization/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
  from tensorflow.contrib.factorization.python.ops.gmm import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/factorization/python/ops/gmm.py", line 30, in <module>
  from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import estimator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
  from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
  from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import estimators
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
  from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.base import TensorFlowBaseTransformer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/base.py", line 34, in <module>
  from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import estimator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 50, in <module>
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io import data_feeder
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io.dask_io import extract_dask_data
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/dask_io.py", line 26, in <module>
import dask.dataframe as dd
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from .io import (from_array, from_pandas, from_bcolz,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/io/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                             
from .csv import read_csv, to_csv, read_table                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/io/csv.py", line 147, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                
CPU_COUNT = psutil.cpu_count()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cpu_count'
```

Could someone please help me in figuring out the cause for this issue ?

Comment: It looks like dask/psutil is misinstalled. Try installing them again or re-installing them.

Comment: @drpng Thanks for your suggestion. I will try it now and update you the result.